# Как переустановить Windows 7 из recovery-раздела на ноутбуке ASUS без установки встроенных драйверов и утилит от производителя ноутбука?

Tags: windows, asus

При переустановке предустановленной ОС из recovery-раздела на HDD ноутбука, автоматически устанавливается куча ненужных программ, устаревших драйверов. Как мне переустановить чистую систему Windows 7? Лицензионный ключ от предустановленной системы, принадлежащий мне, не подходит для чистого дистрибутива Windows 7

Машинка: ASUS N76v

Comment: А почему такая привязанность к лицензии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сложно но можно - на скрытом диске есть папка с дистрибутивами данных утилит, просто удаляете не нужные...

Или с помощью vbs скрипта:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
regKey = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\"
DigitalProductId = WshShell.RegRead(regKey & "DigitalProductId")
Win8ProductName = "Windows Product Name: " & WshShell.RegRead(regKey & "ProductName") & vbNewLine
Win8ProductID = "Windows Product ID: " & WshShell.RegRead(regKey & "ProductID") & vbNewLine
Win8ProductKey = ConvertToKey(DigitalProductId)
strProductKey ="Windows 8 Key: " & Win8ProductKey
Win8ProductID = Win8ProductName & Win8ProductID & strProductKey
MsgBox(Win8ProductKey)
MsgBox(Win8ProductID)
Function ConvertToKey(regKey)
Const KeyOffset = 52
isWin8 = (regKey(66) \ 6) And 1
regKey(66) = (regKey(66) And &HF7) Or ((isWin8 And 2) * 4)
j = 24
Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
Do
Cur = 0
y = 14
Do
Cur = Cur * 256
Cur = regKey(y + KeyOffset) + Cur
regKey(y + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24)
Cur = Cur Mod 24
y = y -1
Loop While y >= 0
j = j -1
winKeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & winKeyOutput
Last = Cur
Loop While j >= 0
If (isWin8 = 1) Then
keypart1 = Mid(winKeyOutput, 2, Last)
insert = "N"
winKeyOutput = Replace(winKeyOutput, keypart1, keypart1 & insert, 2, 1, 0)
If Last = 0 Then winKeyOutput = insert & winKeyOutput
End If
a = Mid(winKeyOutput, 1, 5)
b = Mid(winKeyOutput, 6, 5)
c = Mid(winKeyOutput, 11, 5)
d = Mid(winKeyOutput, 16, 5)
e = Mid(winKeyOutput, 21, 5)
ConvertToKey = a & "-" & b & "-" & c & "-" & d & "-" & e
End Function
```

Запускаете - получаете ключ, сохраняете - качаете установочный дистрибутив соответствующий установленному у вас - ставите - вводите ключ - ставите необходимые драйвера с сайта производителя...

Примечание:
УСТАНАВЛИВАЕМАЯ НОВАЯ ВЕРСИЯ ОС WINDOWS ДОЛЖНА ТОЧНО СОВПАДАТЬ С ТОЙ ЧТО БЫЛА УСТАНОВЛЕНА У ВАС ДО ЭТОГО

Windows 7 x32 Home == Windows 7 x32 Home
Windows 7 x64 Home == Windows 7 x64 Home
Windows 7 x32 Profesional == Windows 7 x32 Profesional
Windows 7 x64 Ultimate == Windows 7 x64 Ultimate